# PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine Callback

Tags: c, windows, drivers

Does the main thread for the process start executing right after creation, or does it begin after the completion of the call back routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be documented, which implies that there is no guarantee that the thread will not start executing before the callback routine returns.

However, the documentation for the [`CreateProcessNotifyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542860%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) routine says:

> For a new process, the CreateProcessNotifyEx routine is called after the initial thread is created, but before the thread begins running. The driver can cause the process-creation operation to fail by changing the CreateInfo->CreationStatus member to an NTSTATUS error code.

So, if you need your notification routine to complete before the initial thread starts running, use [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).